# what the main difference of using return ""; and return null ?

Tags: null, return

```
def getDocumentId() {
    SessionAttribute sessAttribute = new SessionManager(this).getSessionAttribute("DocumentId")
    if (sessAttribute != null) {
        return sessAttribute.getAttrValue();
    } 
    return "";
```

please explain why return ""; is being used here and where and when we use suppose to use return null.

Answer (score 0):

"" would be a pointer to an empty string (a pointer to a zero character (could be 16 bits if unicode). Null would be a pointer value of zero.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is Java code,you have not tagged your question.

Null would mean you are returning a reference to a null object, meaning thereby there is no actual object which exist in memory. Hence you would be returning null.

"" would mean you are returning an empty String. This is still a valid String object.

Comment: what if there is no return ""; in above code. What would  go wrong ? i Cant add more codes its part of my project.

Comment: What you return from the function depends on the return type of the function. If the function signature expects you to return a String, then if you won't return anything, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`""` is still a string object, and you can call methods on it without the fear of exceptions. It's a pretty common pattern to use it instead of `null` to streamline your code and avoid having to explicitly check for `null`s when you use this return value.